# How do I find the documentation for shell builtins for z/OS?

Tags: posix, ksh, zos, uss

I am trying to figure out how the dot command behaves under /bin/sh, i.e.

```
. sourcedfile
```

but I am having trouble finding it. I can find other builtins like cd with man, e.g.

```
man cd
```

but I am not sure what to enter for the dot command (man . doesn't work).
The online docs to the [UNIX System Services Command Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=reference-shell-command-descriptions) didn't seem to have anything either.

Comment: After some hunting, I found some doc in the POSIX sh description: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09

Search for:

dot - execute commands in the current environment

which says:
"If file does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by PATH to find the directory containing file..."

Comment: What I don't know is if tcsh 'dot command' is exactly conformant with the POSIX definition? I know bash is 'different' by default

Comment: I'm not used to `tcsh`. Anyway, the only thing I found about `tcsh`, and file sourcing is the `source` tcsh built-in (in the book you listed). Interestingly, when I try `. test.sh` under tcsh, I'm getting `/bin/.: EDC5111I Permission denied..` This looks to me as if `tcsh` does not support `.` as "sourcing built-in", but has an own built-in called `source`. Unfortunately, this built-in is only very briefly explained in the manual.

Comment: I just saw this at the start of the z/OS shell description:

The z/OS shell is based on the KornShell that originated on a UNIX system. As implemented for z/OS UNIX System Services, this shell conforms to POSIX standard 1003.2-1992.

Comment: This documentation on ksh: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/dot.1.asp does seem to match what I'm seeing.

Comment: The standard shell `/bin/sh` was original ported by Mortice Kern Co. from their korn shell. You were asking about the C shell `/bin/tcsh`, which is the second shell that is part of z/OS. The bash shell is available, too, but is not part of the z/OS discribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csh and tcsh don't have a `.` command; it only has [`source`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=tics-source-built-in-command-tcsh-read-execute-commands-from-name) command, which does the same.

The standard tcsh manpage describes the builtins in the `tcsh` manpage, but it seems that on zOS this is split to different pages; [there's a list here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=descriptions-tcsh-invoke-c-shell#cshell__title__43).

You should never use the POSIX sh documentation for csh; while it's superficially similar there are also many differences, and it's just a different shell.

---

It's also generally discouraged to use tcsh, as it has a number of limitations such as lack of functions, limited redirection, limited parser, and a few others that tend to cause a world of pain for non-trivial scripts.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I asked the wrong question, thinking that the /bin/sh shell was tcsh when it appears to be a variant of 'korn shell'. See my update and comment

Comment: Once I realized where I was off base from your comments, I finally found the dot command: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=descriptions-dot-run-shell-file-in-current-environment